# AsyncTask - Why can I access layout widgets in the doInBackground method?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

From my understanding, the `doInBackground` method should not have access to the layout views. So why does the following code work? As you can see, I access the `ProgressBar` from `doInBackground`

```
private class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        progressBar.setMax(integers[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= integers[0]; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Finished!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the declaration of progressBar?

Comment: are you sure your code is working?

Comment: It's declared as a member variable in the MainActivity and assigned in onCreate with findViewById. And yes it definitely works. Just tested it again.

Comment: `publishProgress(i);`. Not only you shoud supply the progress position but also the max value. `publishProgress(max, i);`. Adapt your `onProgressUpdate()` to set the max too.

Comment: But this sets the max with every progress update. Is that not a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the widget code it checks the thread, if not UI it creates a Runnable and posts it to the UI Thread :

```
private synchronized void refreshProgress(int id, int progress, boolean fromUser,
            boolean animate) {
        if (mUiThreadId == Thread.currentThread().getId()) {
            doRefreshProgress(id, progress, fromUser, true, animate);
        } else {
            if (mRefreshProgressRunnable == null) {
                mRefreshProgressRunnable = new RefreshProgressRunnable();
            }
            final RefreshData rd = RefreshData.obtain(id, progress, fromUser, animate);
            mRefreshData.add(rd);
            if (mAttached && !mRefreshIsPosted) {
                post(mRefreshProgressRunnable);
                mRefreshIsPosted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

`RefreshProgressRunnable` : Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I guess I should still avoid it and handle it in one of the UI methods?

Comment: Yes, without checking all widget code there would be no guarantee that it would post a Runnable to do the action.  `AsyncTask` has a `onPreExecute()`callback - use this for UI related setup then use `onProgressUpdate()` callback specifically for updating UI during background operations.

Comment: Well I need access to the value passed in doInBackground to know what the maximum value of the progress bar is. I do it like this now: publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);

Comment: Why is that a requirement - thats just a requirement you've created? Create a constructor that takes in the value, and use it in `onPreExecute` to set max & `doInBackground` for the loop. You can use a`Void` type as a passed value into `doInBackground`